# Why my <package>-config.cmake have <package>_include_dir and <package>_librairies empty

Tags: cmake, yaml-cpp

I am trying to make a cross-platform CMake for my project (Windows and Linux).
I need to use external libraries (yaml-cpp). On Linux, I just had to do an apt get and use `find_package`. But on Windows, I need to append the `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` in order for my program to find the `yaml-cpp-config.cmake`.

So I start by installing yaml-cpp (https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp) with CMake GUI 3.16 and mingw32 (`mingw32-make install`).

I have tried the library on a hello world project, and it works fine.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

project (yaml_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

message (STATUS "Yaml-cpp include = $ENV{YAML_CPP_INCLUDE_DIR}")
message (STATUS "Yaml-cpp library = $ENV{YAML_CPP_LIBRARIES}")

include_directories ($ENV{YAML_CPP_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(yaml_test main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(yaml_test $ENV{YAML_CPP_LIBRARIES})
```

But now, I want to include the library in my project and use `find_package`. But the `yaml-cpp-config.cmake` looks like this:

```
# - Config file for the yaml-cpp package
# It defines the following variables
#  YAML_CPP_INCLUDE_DIR - include directory
#  YAML_CPP_LIBRARIES    - libraries to link against

# Compute paths
get_filename_component(YAML_CPP_CMAKE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)
set(YAML_CPP_INCLUDE_DIR "")

# Our library dependencies (contains definitions for IMPORTED targets)
include("${YAML_CPP_CMAKE_DIR}/yaml-cpp-targets.cmake")

# These are IMPORTED targets created by yaml-cpp-targets.cmake
set(YAML_CPP_LIBRARIES "")
```

The `YAML_CPP_INCLUDE_DIR` and `YAML_CPP_LIBRARIES` variables are empty, and even if CMake found `yaml-cpp-config.cmake`, It doesn't work. So what do I have missing in the installation of yaml-cpp? Should I have set the paths by hand?

Comment: Note, that description at the top of `yaml-cpp-config.cmake` script refers to **CMake variables** `YAML_CPP_INCLUDE_DIR` and `YAML_CPP_LIBRARIES`, which are accessed via `${XXX}` notation. But you use notation `$ENV{XXX}`, which is intended for **environment variables** - completely different set of variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The absence of definition of `YAML_CPP_INCLUDE_DIR` and `YAML_CPP_LIBRARIES` variables is the issue with the yaml-cpp project which is already reported [here](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/issues/774).

Instead of variables described in this config file, use target `yaml-cpp`:

```
add_executable(yaml_test main.cpp)
# This provides both include directories and libraries.
target_link_libraries(yaml_test yaml-cpp)
```

Linking with an IMPORTED target (`yaml-cpp` in this case) is known as CMake "modern way".

Comment: ok, it seems magic for me, but by adding find_package(yaml-cpp PATHS $ENV{yaml-cpp_ROOT}), with yaml-cpp_ROOT in my environments variables, it works like you say ...

Comment: In fact, no need of PATHS $ENV{yaml-cpp_ROOT} in find_package. By the way, thank you